# Server not recognizing that there are bytes written in the client NetworkStream

Tags: c#

I am having problems with a client NetworkStream. Though I think its more accurate to say that the server just isn't reading the data that's written in the stream. (Also the client has established a connection to the server so that isn't the issue.)

There is a little bit more of the Echoer class but basically everything important ends at the do while loop.
So the Thread should be stuck waiting for user input in the do while loop. And it is, but the problem is that when I write something to the ownClient NetworkStream it isn't registered and the do while loop just keeps on looping and it never reads of the stream presumably because it thinks there's nothing in there, but there actually is. And I know that there is, because when I try reading from the stream where the TCPListener is it works and the server successfully reads the integers I need. But in the case of doing it in the Echoer class it absolutely wets the bed and just gets stuck never going in the if(ownStream.DataAvailable) statement even though I am more than 100% sure there are bytes written to the stream. I am pretty new to servering as I checked out how it works essentially just to try to make one of my projects multiplayer but someone told me I should use Asynchronous Server Socket instead of making new Threads and I'm thinking of doing that but first I would like to know if there's an alternate solution without having to learn to use and re-write a bunch of stuff.
(Also you can ignore TCPClient enemy since it has nothing to do with the current issue and I edited out the code that includes it along with some other stuff because stackoverflow isn't letting me post this)

````
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 1302);
listener.Start();

try
{
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        TcpClient client2 = listener.AcceptTcpClient();    
        ServerSide.Echoer opp1 = new ServerSide.Echoer(client2,client,true);
        ServerSide.Echoer opp2 = new ServerSide.Echoer(client, client2, false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {        
    }
    ```
this is basically the entire code for the server Thread. The only thing it does is accepting 2 clients and creating 2 instances of the Echoer class, feeding the clients into its constructor.  From then on another Thread gets started  within the Echoer class and it handles everything.
````

```
internal class Echoer
{
    
    
    
    NetworkStream ownStream;
    bool turnPriority { get; set; }
    public Echoer(TcpClient enemy,TcpClient own,bool turnPriority)
    {            
        this.turnPriority=turnPriority;                       
        ownStream = own.GetStream();
        Thread thread = new(run);
        thread.Start();
        
    }
    public void run()
    {                           
            byte[] pieceIndexBuffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            byte[] tileIndexBuffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            byte[] previousTileIndexBuffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            if (turnPriority)
            {
                do
                {                    
                    if (ownStream.DataAvailable)
                    {                        
                        ownStream.Read(pieceIndexBuffer, 0, pieceIndexBuffer.Length);
                        ownStream.Read(tileIndexBuffer, 0, pieceIndexBuffer.Length);
                        ownStream.Read(previousTileIndexBuffer, 0, previousTileIndexBuffer.Length);                          
                        break;
                    }                        
                } while (true);
}
```

Comment: What is your actual goal? If you just want to have a few computers talk to each other I would recommend using a higher level protocol, like a message bus, or some RPC framework.

Comment: @JonasH Well my goal is to essentially have  a turn based stream read and write from 2 computers. What I mean by that is: 
1. One of the clients sends data through his own stream to the server
2.The server sends the data that the first client sent through the stream of the second client
3. the second client sends data through his own stream, the server receives it and sends it through to the first client and so on and so on. I already have functionality set for that but as I said I had to cut the code short. I just want to know if its possible to fix the issue without too much hassle.

Comment: For that kind of application I would just use something like [NetMQ](https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/receiving-sending/), but there are a huge number of alternatives. The important thing in my opinion is the ability to send *messages*, and not having to handle all the low level reading/writing yourself. Combine this with some serialization library like json .net or protobuf .net and you should have a fairly simple way to send objects between your applications.

Comment: @JonasH I don't need to send objects, just bytes. And more specifically 3 integers.

Comment: @JonasH ah ok I'm stupid I thought you meant serialising custom objects since I didn't have time to properly look cause I had to go out but now that I look at NetMQ it does look pretty handy. Although I am still wondering why what I've written doesn't work.